# Securesocial 0.2.5 with Google and Playframework 1.2.7 on localhost

Tags: playframework, localhost, securesocial

I have sucesfully installed securesocial in my play 1.2.7 app and it 
working for Yahoo. But I am having an issue with google. Please help me thanks in advance.

> securesocial.google.requestTokenURL=https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken
>   securesocial.google.accessTokenURL=https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken
>   securesocial.google.authorizationURL=https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken
>   securesocial.google.scope=http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people
>   securesocial.google.consumerKey=mykey
>
> securesocial.google.consumerSecret=mysecret

But I am getting the following exception.

16:00:24,934 DEBUG ~ Adding uri: https://www.google.com:443 for channel [id: 0x00925f6d, /192.168.1.75:56337 => www.google.com/74.125.236.114:443]
16:00:24,935 ERROR ~ Request token is missing in OpenID+OAuth callback.  Provider: google
securesocial.provider.AuthenticationException

Comment: Perhaps you use very old versions of SecureSocial and Playframework. You have to migrate to newer versions with OAuth 2.0. OAuth 1.0 is deprecated for google access: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref. Maybe they don't support your requests.

Comment: Thanks piesnikowski i will try that.